# Criteria Query with multiple cascaded joins involved

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I have three entities: `Block`, `View`and `TargetBlock`and want to create a JPA Criteria query for the following sql.

```
select * from Block INNER JOIN TargetBlock tb ON tb.blockID = b.blockID INNER JOIN view v ON tb.viewID = v.viewID
```

Block has many views and many `TargetBlocks`.

Comment: This is neither a valid Criteria or JPQL query. What is your question exactly?

Comment: i want to convert this query to a criteria query... the second inner join is joining targetBlock's viewId with viewId from View entity. I am not sure how to add this on condition in criteria query as default is inner join will be blockID.

Answer (score 0):

For documentation of the Criteria API see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Join